# What is StackOverflow's code analysis and code style settings?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, code-formatting, code

Which tools SO uses to validate the code?

- Is Code Analysis used?
- Which rules are included?

To validate the code style

- Which tool is used?
- Which rules are included?

Comment: Are you asking about the tools used by the Stack Exchange development team?

Comment: @Michael Yes, exactly. Jeff posted the tools they used to build SO ( http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/ ), this question is kind of a request for a bit more info.

Comment: There are code analysis tools??